# Passing Gtk.Window to a class?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I'm learning interface design in Python 3 and Glade with GObject introspection, and I don't understand how you can pass another variable (or class?) to another class, like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class DemoWindow(Gtk.Window):
```

And what is the difference between class() and class - Does class() initiate the `__init__`function, and class is used for referencing other functions, like `class.function()`?

And is it possible to pass a variable to a class and use it in other functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `class MyClassName(SomeOtherClassName):` defines a class called `MyClassName` which inherits from the (previously existing) class `SomeOtherClassName`. So in your example `DemoWindow` inherits from the class `Gtk.Window`.

> And what is the difference between class() and class

`MyClassName(args)` creates a new object of the `MyClassName` class and calls its `__init__` method with the arguments `args`. `MyClassName.my_function()` calls `my_function` without going through an object, i.e. no `self` argument will be passed implicitly (unless `my_function` is defined as a class method).

> And is it possible to pass a variable to a class and use it in other functions?

Sure. Just let the `__init__` function take it as an argument and then set it as an attribute on `self`. Other methods of the class can then use it through `self`.

Comment: Ah when experimenting I was defining all my variables in __init__, instead of just writing var = "xyz" outsiide of __init__